# PersistentVolumeClaim not claiming a matching and available PersistentVolume

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims, rke

I have a `PersistentVolume` created locally:

```
$ kubectl get pv example-pv -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"PersistentVolume","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"example-pv"},"spec":{"accessModes":["ReadWriteOnce"],"capacity":{"storage":"10Gi"},"local":{"path":"/var/k8s-volumes/first"},"nodeAffinity":{"required":{"nodeSelectorTerms":[{"matchExpressions":[{"key":"kubernetes.io/hostname","operator":"In","values":["rke2-server-node-1"]}]}]}},"persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy":"Delete","storageClassName":"local-storage","volumeMode":"Filesystem"}}
  creationTimestamp: "2023-04-26T02:14:22Z"
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pv-protection
  name: example-pv
  resourceVersion: "4740152"
  uid: 0874cd56-76be-4743-b24f-6ee7dce5604a
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  local:
    path: /var/k8s-volumes/first
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - rke2-server-node-1
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: local-storage
  volumeMode: Filesystem
status:
  phase: Available
```

And for some reason my `PersistentVolumeClaim` is not matching it...

```
$ kubectl get pvc -n namespace -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
  metadata:
    annotations:
      meta.helm.sh/release-name: manager
      meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: manager
    creationTimestamp: "2023-04-26T02:38:02Z"
    finalizers:
    - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
    labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: manager
      app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
      app.kubernetes.io/name: manager
      app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.1.3
      helm.sh/chart: manager-0.1.0
    name: manager-pvc-pg
    namespace: manager
    resourceVersion: "4740252"
    uid: efa5460f-7aef-4a0d-a4a1-f902868cc38b
  spec:
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 10Gi
    volumeMode: Filesystem
  status:
    phase: Pending
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
```

I saw a similar question elsewhere and his issue was that there was no resource attempting to use his PVC, but that is not the case for me since I have a pod:

```
$ kubectl describe pod -n manager manager-pg-674df946fd-nqplc
Name:             manager-pg-674df946fd-nqplc
Namespace:        manager
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             <none>
Labels:           app.kubernetes.io/component=postgres
                  app.kubernetes.io/instance=manager
                  app.kubernetes.io/name=manager
                  pod-template-hash=674df946fd
Annotations:      kubernetes.io/psp: global-unrestricted-psp
Status:           Pending
IP:
IPs:              <none>
Controlled By:    ReplicaSet/manager-pg-674df946fd
Containers:
  manager-pg:
    Image:      registry:5000/postgresql12:12.13
    Port:       5432/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Environment:
      PGDATA:             /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      POSTGRES_USER:      user
      PGUSER:             user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD:  <set to the key 'databasePassword' in secret 'shared-secret'>  Optional: false
      POSTGRES_DB:        dbname
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-w6wsl (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False
Volumes:
  postgres-data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  manager-pvc-pg
    ReadOnly:   false
  kube-api-access-w6wsl:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  2m4s (x4 over 17m)  default-scheduler  0/4 nodes are available: 4 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/4 nodes are available: 4 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
```

---

Edit 1, adding more output based on questions asked:

There is a storageclass present, but I am intentionally not using it (storageClass is set to "" on my PVC because I am trying to get statically provisioned volumes working)

```
$ kubectl get storageclass
NAME         PROVISIONER             RECLAIMPOLICY   VOLUMEBINDINGMODE      ALLOWVOLUMEEXPANSION   AGE
local-path   rancher.io/local-path   Delete          WaitForFirstConsumer   false                  11d
```

I am not trying to use the csidriver.

```
$ kubectl get csidriver
No resources found
```

Comment: Can you run the commands : **kubectl get storageclass** and **kubectl get csidriver**, let me know the output?

Comment: Try to update your K8s deployment's securityContext to include "fsGroupChangePolicy: OnRootMismatch". Refer to [Allow volume ownership to be only set after fs formatting. #69699](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/69699) and [Skip Volume Ownership Change](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/tree/master/keps/sig-storage/695-skip-permission-change), which mayhelp to resolve your issue.

Comment: Hi @VeeraNagireddy thanks for engaging. I added the output you requested, however please note I am specifically trying to get static volumes to work without using a storageclass. I will look into what you mentioned in your second comment presently though.

Comment: Turns out volume ownership was not the issue in my case @VeeraNagireddy - I had a storageclass mix up going on. I posted my answer below.

Comment: If no StorageClass is specified, then the default StorageClass will be used, please have look at my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so even though I was explicitly trying to test *not using StorageClasses* (as in, statically provisioned Volume) the issue still ended up being related to StorageClass.

As a test, I manually specified `storageClassName` on my `PersistentVolumeClaim` to try and get it to attach to the matching `PersistentVolume` and it gave an error that the storage class did not match. I thought having no storage class specified on my PVC would let it pick up any matching PV, but since my PV had a storage class specified of "local-storage" this meant only PVCs explicitly specifying a storage class of "local-storage" would get matched with it. To fix it I removed the storage class name on my PV and then things worked accordingly. I think I could have alternately have specified `local-storage` on my PVC but that is not the test case I was interested in.

Relevant excerpts from the documentation:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#class

> A PV can have a class, which is specified by setting the storageClassName attribute to the name of a StorageClass. A PV of a particular class can only be bound to PVCs requesting that class. A PV with no storageClassName has no class and can only be bound to PVCs that request no particular class.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#class-1

> A claim can request a particular class by specifying the name of a StorageClass using the attribute storageClassName. Only PVs of the requested class, ones with the same storageClassName as the PVC, can be bound to the PVC.
>
> PVCs don't necessarily have to request a class. A PVC with its storageClassName set equal to "" is always interpreted to be requesting a PV with no class, so it can only be bound to PVs with no class (no annotation or one set equal to ""). A PVC with no storageClassName is not quite the same and is treated differently by the cluster, depending on whether the DefaultStorageClass admission plugin is turned on.